# Can wicked.io integrate with keycloak, in a way that keycloak will provide client ids and secrets, and of course, authentication?

Tags: oauth, keycloak, kong, ibm-api-management

I'm looking for an API management system, that will intergrate with Keycloak (Keycloak should provide all of the authentication). 
Wicked.io (kong based) looks nice.

I've tried adding oAuth2 as an auth method, but wicked keeps generating its own client ids and secrets.

Is there any way to do this with wicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wicked.haufe.io maintainer here.

Combining wicked/Kong with KeyCloak may not be a very good idea. Wicked solves a lot of the problems KeyCloak is intended to solve as well, and the overlap is quite big, e.g. doing identity federation (SAML, OAuth2) to an OAuth2 workflow and all that.

KeyCloak and wicked/Kong follow different principles though; KeyCloak issues tokens which are validated via a KeyCloak library inside your services. This more or less replaces the API Gateway - it's implemented inside your services, based on the KeyCloak library.

wicked/Kong as a contrast is built up differently, where the big differentiator is the API Portal wicked provides on top of Kong and that you have a dedicated API Gateway (Kong). Wicked provides you with its own client credentials, and it also wants to do the entire authentication and authorization bit. What you get in exchange for that is the self service API Portal; if you don't need that, you will probably not need wicked.

What you **can** do is to federate a KeyCloak OAuth2 flow into wicked, by having KeyCloak act either as a SAML or OAuth2 identity provider. You would then register your KeyCloak Authorization Server as an identity provider with wicked (using a single service provider (SAML) or client (OAuth2)). The "but" here is that you would still need to provide an entry point to your services which do **not** go via the KeyCloak library.

wicked/Kong always works like this: It takes away the need to implement Authentication/Authorization inside your services; instead you need to check for the headers `X-Authenticated-UserId` and `X-Authenticated-Scope`. With wicked, this will typically contain something like `sub=<some id>`, also depending on which type of identity provider(s) you have configured wicked to use. But this approach usually **replaces** KeyCloak. The upside is that you can have one single entry point to your services (=Kong), and you have a quite lightweight way how you can protect arbitrary services - not only services written in languages KeyCloak supports! - behind an API Gateway while providing self service access (with configurable plans, documentation,...) via an API Portal.

All these things are obviously somewhat complicated; wicked is extremely flexible in its usage, but it's not really meant to be combined with KeyCloak (which is likewise. It all boils down to really understanding the use case and finding a solution architecture which solves your use case in the best way.

If your use cases involve an API Portal and API documentation (it should), going wicked/Kong may be a good possibility. If it doesn't, you may be happier sticking to KeyCloak (which you can see as a headless API Management system with a decentralized gateway of you want).

**Disclaimer**: My knowledge on KeyCloak is somewhat outdated; it may be that there are updates which also go into the API Portal direction, but of this I am not aware.

Comment: Thanks! Since we want keycloak for user management, we'll probably use gravitee.io, with keycloak for authorization/authentication.